# Similarities between C++ and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am C++ programmer and in C++ I used some thing that I want
corresponding those things in Ruby.
please help me.

In C++ , I can write thess program but in Ruby I can't:

1 -

```
  int i,x;
  int sum=0;
  for( x=0 ; x <= 50 ; x++ ) {
      cin >> i;
      sum = sum + ( x + i ) ;
  }
  cout << sum;
```

2 -

```
int a,b,c,d;
    while( 1 ) {
       cin >> a >> b >> c >>d ;
       if( a < 0 || b < 0 )
          break;
       cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << endl;
    }
```

thanks.

Comment: Translating C++ to Ruby line-by-line is only slightly easier than translating it character-by-character.

Comment: Two different programming languages aren't going to use the same method for reading and writing standard output. Here is a link to a tutorial on basic Ruby: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/basictutorial.htm#_Hello_World You should read this before you go any further

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not?

1.

```
sum = 0
0.upto(49) {|x| sum += gets.chomp.to_i}
puts sum
```

2.

```
begin
  a,b,c,d = gets.chomp.to_i,gets.chomp.to_i,gets.chomp.to_i,gets.chomp.to_i
end until(a<0 or b<0)
puts "#{a} #{b} #{c} #{d}"
```

Comment: Although I just re-read the q and 2. should only print unless a<0 or b<0 8(